# ArgumentError in FacilitiesController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, databasedotcom-gem

I am running a tutorial to create my first app on Ruby on Rails and find the following issue:

ArgumentError in FacilitiesController#index

bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
Rails.root: /Users/andreucasadella/rails_projects/DF12-Demo-master

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/facilities_controller.rb:7:in `index'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None

Comment: What is on this line? app/controllers/facilities_controller.rb:7

Comment: @facilities = Facility__c.all

Comment: Try this @facilities = Facility.all

Comment: I just tried but did not work. 

Facility__c is the API object name in database.com so I am pretty sure it has to be @facilities = Facility__c.all

Comment: This is pretty much impossible to answer without some  more context

Comment: I am following this tutorial:
http://events.developerforce.com/conferences/dreamforce?session=10701
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=XHlD7Rqz7K4

This is the github project: I have not change anything at all: https://github.com/jeffdonthemic/DF12-Demo